# Issue in iText PDF converter

Tags: pdf, itext

Working on itext and PDF through acroFields, and facing some issue, while filling different data in multiple Lable of Same type.

eg Lable name :  Customer List, which appears multiple times in PDF form

Customer List
Customer List
Customer List
Customer List

and I want to replace this with different names.

Regards,
Guru

Comment: By "Lable" do you mean some AcroForm text field? Or the (internal) name of some AcroForm field? Or the fixed label text near some AcroForm field? Probably you should share some example pdf to illustrate.

Comment: AcroForm fields

Comment: Participant List
 1. Guru  "Customer Name"
 2. Nik   "Customer Name"
 3. Sunny  "Customer Name"
 4. Ford  "Customer Name"
 
All are having same AcroFields name "Customer Name" in the same form

Comment: If those fields have the same full name as form fields, they **are** the same field, merely different visualizations of it, and, therefore, have the same content. If this is not intended, the PDF form should be corrected accordingly.